# QLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone know what this means? not a very experience programmer.

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'***.***.*.' (using password: NO)SELECT * FROM ******_Students

code in StudentDataSet

```
require_once ('Models/StudentData.php'); 
require_once ('Models/Database.php');


class StudentsDataSet {
protected $_dbHandle, $_dbInstance;

public function __construct() 

{
    $this-> _dbInstance = Database::getInstance();
    $this-> _dbHandle = $this-> _dbInstance-> getdbConnection();
}

public function fetchAllStudents() {
$sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM MUD193_Students'; // put your students table name
echo $sqlQuery; //helpful for debugging to see what SQL query has been created

$statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); // prepare PDO statement
$statement->execute(); // execute the PDO statement

$dataSet = [];
while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
$dataSet[] = new StudentData($row); }
return $dataSet; }
```

Code in StudentData

```
<?php

class StudentDataClass {

private $_id, $_firstName, $_lastName, $_international, $_courseID;

public function __construct($dbRow) {
    $this->_id = $dbRow['id'];
    $this->_firstName = $dbRow['first_name'];
    $this->_lastName = $dbRow['last_name'];
    if ($dbRow['international'])
        $this->_international = 'yes';
    else
        $this->_international = 'no'; $this->_courseID = $dbRow['courseID'];
}

public function getStudentID() {
    return $this->_id;
}

}
```

Code in Databse

```
<?php

class Database {

protected static $_dbInstance = null;
protected $_dbHandle;

public static function getInstance() {
    $username = '****';
    $password = '****';
    $host = '*******';
    $dbName = '****';
    if (self::$_dbInstance === null) { 
        self::$_dbInstance = new self($username, $password, $host, $dbName);
    }
    return self::$_dbInstance;
    }

    private function __construct($username, $password, $host, $database) {
    try {
        $this->_dbHandle = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=
    $database;  $username, $password");
    } // creates database handle with connection info
    catch (PDOException $e) { // catch any failure to connect to database
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    }

    public function getdbConnection() {
    return $this->_dbHandle; // returns the database handle to be used elsewhere
    }

    public function __destruct() {
    $this->_dbHandle = null; // destroys the destroys the database handle
    }

    }
```

Comment: It means you're trying to connect to a mysql database without a username and said db is denying you access.

Comment: @MikeB I've declare user name & password in the database file. Which I call in StudentDataSet

Answer (score 0):

This is a `Access denied error`. You should check your database username and password with which you login

Comment: @user3157941 No it's not.. did you read the error message? You're not sending a username OR password.

Comment: @MikeB I've declare user name & password in the database file. Which I call in StudentDataSet. not sure why the link isn't working? thanks

Comment: Check the username, password, host, dbname they're all correct. any other idea's. think might have something to do with the link but I'm not sure. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Define your;

- **Database Name**
- **Database Username**
- **Database User Password**

Probably script could not reach variables that you defined.

If you give more information like which language you are using to connect database, we can help you better.

Comment: Using PHP, any ideas? Thanx

Comment: Did you change $username = '****'; $password = '****'; $host = '*******'; $dbName = '****'; to your values? Because if you don't send your information when you call your class, class is using this information to connect db.

Comment: I change my $username= '*'; . Etc to hide info on stack overflow, so other people can't access the database... But I have fill them with the correct values in my actual code